# Bug whitelist_name in prune filter in logstash?

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, logstash

This is my code:

```
 filter {
   json {
     source => "message"
     remove_field => "message"
   } 

   mutate {
     remove_field => "message"
     add_field => ["r","%{[M][result]]autState]}"]
     add_field => ["n", "%{[serviceLogicalId]}"]
     add_field => ["tsc", "%{[T][0][timestamp]}"]
     add_field => ["rtc", "%{[T][0][duration]}"]
     add_field => ["nc", "%{[T][0][transactionName]}"]
     add_field => ["pro", "%{[applicationUUAA]}"]
     add_field => ["con", "%{[aap]}"]
     add_field => ["c", "%{[callingChannel]}"]
     add_field => ["p", "%{[productService]}"]
     add_field => ["es", "services"]
     add_field => ["ci", "%{[cloneId]}"]
     add_field => ["m", "%{[accessMedium]}"]
     add_field => ["s", "%{[productService]}"]
     add_field => ["ui", "%{[contactId]}"] 
     add_field => ["ts", "%{timestamp}"]        
   }

   prune { 
     whitelist_names => ["es", "d", "r", "m", "tsc", "n", "rtc", "nc", "pro", "con", "ci", "ui", "c", "p", "s"] 
   }  
 }  
 output {
   elasticsearch {
   host => "192.168.2.101"
   index => "services"                         
 }
```

}

I want to insert the fields in whitelist_names but fields come out of the output besides these (timestamp, contactId, productService, accessMedium, cloneId, productService, callingChannel, aap, applicationUUAA, serviceLogicalId also come through to ES).

Only this fields, the fields that aren't array.

Comment: It's not very clear what your issue is from your description. Would it be possible to show an example of what you have written so far and tell us what you expect to happen and what is/isn't happening?

Comment: I am trying to insert six fields in my database from a json and I am using whitelist_name for this but this filter insert more fields , i think the problem is that the added fields are not array. The code is :prune { 
    whitelist_names => ["es","d","r","m","tsc","n","rtc","nc","pro","con","ci","ui","c","p","s"]
 
  }

Comment: I'm still unclear, please update the question with the entire filter

Comment: I changed the question .

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand what you want to do, although I have never done it myself before, I will try to answer

Comment: Does the current (incorrect) document that is being written to Elasticsearch contain all of the old fields, plus the new "es" (etc) fields, plus the logstash fields (@timestamp, @version)?  It might help to see the current output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the solution for this problem :

```
 filter {
json {
 source => "message"
 remove_field => "message"
 target => "e."

  }

 mutate {    
  add_field => ["r","%{[e.][M][result]]autState]}"]
  add_field => ["n", "%{[e.][serviceLogicalId]}"]
  add_field => ["tsc", "%{[e.][T][0][timestamp]}"]
  add_field => ["rtc", "%{[e.][T][0][duration]}"]
  add_field => ["nc", "%{[e.][T][0][transactionName]}"]
  add_field => ["pro", "%{[e.][applicationUUAA]}"]
  add_field => ["con", "%{[e.][aap]}"]
  add_field => ["c", "%{[e.][callingChannel]}"]
  add_field => ["p", "%{[e.][productService]}"]
  add_field => ["es", "services"]
  add_field => ["ci", "%{[e.][cloneId]}"]
  add_field => ["m", "%{[e.][accessMedium]}"]
  add_field => ["s", "%{[e.][productService]}"]
  add_field => ["ui", "%{[e.][contactId]}"] 
  add_field => ["ts", "%{[e.][timestamp]}"] 

  }

prune {
   whitelist_names => ["es", "d", "r", "m", "tsc", "n", "rtc", "nc", "pro", "con", "ci","ui","c","p", "s"]

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if I understand this filter correctly, you only want the fields you have specified in the prune whitelist_names list to go through to ES. And you want to drop all other fields.

Okay maybe try:

```
 filter {
   json {
     source => "message"
     remove_field => "message"
   }

   mutate {
     add_field => {
       "r" => "%{[M][result]]autState]}",
       "n", "%{[serviceLogicalId]}",
       "tsc", "%{[T][0][timestamp]}",
       "rtc", "%{[T][0][duration]}",
       "nc", "%{[T][0][transactionName]}",
       "pro", "%{[applicationUUAA]}",
       "con", "%{[aap]}",
       "c", "%{[callingChannel]}",
       "p", "%{[productService]}",
       "es", "services",
       "ci", "%{[cloneId]}",
       "m", "%{[accessMedium]}",
       "s", "%{[productService]}",
       "ui", "%{[contactId]}",
       "ts", "%{timestamp}"
     }
   }
   prune {
     whitelist_names => ["es", "d", "r", "m", "tsc", "n", "rtc", "nc", "pro", "con", "ci", "ui", "c", "p", "s"]
     add_tag => [ "pruned" ]
     }
 }

 output {
   elasticsearch {
   host => "192.168.2.101"
   index => "services"
   }
 }
```

I'm not sure why you had remove_field => "message" twice, so I removed it.

I have returned the prune method in, and told it to add_tags, that way you at least know the prune method is being called. Otherwise, there is a small syntax change, but you might want to give it a go and see if this works as desired.

As far as I can tell from the documentation you are using the prune function correctly, if it's still not working you might be best going in to the irc channel (#logstash on freenode.net) to chat with some of the people on there they may have experienced this issue. gl!

Comment: thanks, but my problem is that my input message can have more fields for this I can't use this option .

Comment: the add_tag  option isn't the solution to my problem , I will try other ways . Thank you

Comment: The idea of adding a tag is just to tell you whether that step took place or not, did the tag get added?

Answer (score 0):

The source of your issue is that you are trying to pass whitelist_names a list of fields.
It actually takes a list of regexps.

So in your example "d" "r" "m" "n" will match any field containing those letters.

To do what you want:

```
prune { 
  whitelist_names => ["^es$", "^d$", "^r$", "^m$", "^tsc$", "^n$", "^rtc$", "^nc$", "^pro$", "^con$", "^ci$", "^ui$", "^c$", "^p$", "^s$"] 
}
```